# Twitter Fabric "Show Timelines" Swift example failing with "Cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable"

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I'm implementing the Twitter Fabric iOS Show Timelines example exactly as described in the Twitter documentation:
https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/show-timelines

However, I'm getting a build error:

> Cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable

...on the "required init" line below.

I appreciate any help you can provide this newbie. Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit
import TwitterKit

class ViewController: TWTRTimelineViewController {

    convenience init() {
        let client = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient
        let dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "fabric", APIClient: client)

        self.init(dataSource: dataSource)
    }

    override required init(dataSource: TWTRTimelineDataSource) {
        super.init(dataSource: dataSource)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this in Objective-c? @Kikaida

Answer (score 0):

Also add Following initializer

```
required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()
}
```

Update the method declaration from `TWTRTimelineViewController.h` of TwitterKit header files as follows:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;// __attribute__((unavailable("Use -initWithDataSource: instead")));
```

Here I have commented `__attribute__((unavailable` as we are using this `initWithDataSource:` in our `convenience init`.

This is temporary workaround and anyone can update this answer if needed. I will also post update if any.

Comment: Thanks Zala. The build succeeds, but now i'm getting this: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on the 'let Datasource..." line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kikaida can you provide more info about crash, have you debug your code. Are you using tableView controller in storyboard?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Zala. I'm going to wait for Twitter to fix the bug. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Glad to help, I was also suspecting the twitter bug

Answer (score 0):

Twitter dev support confirms that this is a bug and they'll ship a fix ASAP. Here is the link to the issue on the Twitter dev forums:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/show-timelines-swift-example-failing-with-cannot-override-init-which-has-been-marked-unavailable/37853